# If cell is 5 long add 0 prefix , else leave as is, loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

We have Serial Numbers that have to be reviewed and some of them are 5 digits long but in the database have a 0 prefix, which of course they don't have in the format we receive. So using bits and pieces of other VBA I've got the below, which loops and changes nothing.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

```
Sub SNoReview()

    Dim METER                   As String
    Dim SQL_STRING              As String
    Dim ANSWER                  As String
    Dim CELLADDRESS             As Variant


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("N6").Select

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

        CELLADDRESS = ActiveCell.Address
        METER = ActiveCell.Value

        If Len(METER) = 5 Then
            METER = "0" & (METER)
        Else: METER = (METER)
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your column include numbers? If you are just trying to force all numbers to be 6 digits in length then you can just format them directly

Comment: House keeping: Avoid `Activate` & `Select`. That is not necessary here. You have didn't re-enable screen updating / alerts before ending the sub although.

Comment: The column is serial numbers that can be 10 or more characters from the data I have been working on. It just older data that is 5 digits long, and in our tables to be queried is actually 6 digits with a zero prefix, and Excel just loves losing those zeros

Comment: Did you try the solution below?

Comment: Yep. No effect. Data is anything from 40453 to XKF06944.

Comment: Don’t see how this wouldn’t at least update the numbers. For future reference, this is exactly why your questions should include sample data. I made a bad assumption thinking your range was only numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First acknowledging that @urdearboy has done the hard work here (investigative) ...

In terms of an answer, assuming any data < 6 in length is a numeric or text numeric ... then maybe something like this which converts and formats (from N6 down):

```
Option Explicit

Sub SNoReview()

    Dim vSheet As Worksheet
    Dim vCell As Range

    Set vSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each vCell In vSheet.Range("N6:N" & vSheet.Range("N" & vSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If Len(vCell) < 6 Then
            With vCell
                vCell.NumberFormat = "000000"
                vCell = Val(vCell)
            End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

**Before**

[image: before]

**After**

[image: after]

Comment: Thank you. This works for it's primary function. I then found it interfered with a secondary function but was able to mod this to end up with my desired result. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could just apply a single **Number Format** to the entire range all at once. No need to loop here.

```
Sub sNoReview()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("N6:N" & ws.Range("N" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).NumberFormat = "000000"

End Sub
```

This will not change the format of any number that has LEN > 6

```
000001 From 1
000011 From 11
000111 From 111
001111 From 1111
011111 From 11111
111111 From 111111
```

---

### Your Code

The reason your macro is not working is because you never changed the format. The default of excel is to drop leading 0's so your code was adding them only for them to be removed by excel right after. Gotcha moment for sure.